azure devops npm task takes time compared to other pipeline
i have an npm install task that takes 10-14 mins longer compared to a similar task I have in another project which is about 3 mins. Still takes time but much faster.
they are both using same node version. same OS. and no pipelines running in parallel that could probably(?) slow the job down.
the only difference is they are in a different project.
both are using MS hosted agent.


i have tried importing my pipeline and repo that takes 15 mins to install npm to the project that takes shorter npm install. and it did make install the npm install task faster.

This could be a connectivity/networking issue. Issues in Azure DevOps like the one logged today can also cause problems in the pipelines.

but the MS agent in other project is faster and they're noth MS hosted agents. It happened quite some time too so i don't think it's a network issue.

Are you sure the two pipelines were running npm install against the same package.json file? Were they installing the same packages from the same source, such as the same feed in your Azure Artifacts or any other public source? I suspect if the issue was related to some specific package(s) or the package source from which this npm install task was restoring. Can you please test to create a simplified pipeline to install the same packages from the same source?
